# At what point autolayout constraints are applied to the view?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, autolayout

Is there any delegate or a callback to be called when autolayout constraints are added to a view and the view has been resized?

In my view hierarchy (`NSStackView<--MyContainerView<--MyView`) when i add MyView, I add it to the special `ContainerViewController`'s view as a subview and apply constraints to it - it should fill all the area defined by `ContainerViewController`'s view.

The code looks like this:

```
-(void)addView:(MyView*)view
{
   ContainerViewController *vc = [[ContainerViewController alloc] init];
   [vc addContentView: view]; // autolayout constraints are applied inside like "H:|[view]|" and "V:|[view]|"
   [self.stackView addView: vc.view];
}
```

however, after returning from `addView`, view's frame is still **{0,0,0,0}**.
How can I catch the moment when view is resized appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're after -

but if you want to be informed when the view's frame changes you can listen to the `NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification`:

[**NSView Notifications**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html)

Make sure to read the comments about how to control the enablement of this notification.